# Do we want to exclude questions from the hot network questions list?

Tags: discussion, questions

A common criticism of the [Stack Exchange hot network questions list](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) is that questions that make it onto the list are often not representative of the their parent sites. I would certainly argue that is the case for [Is semen retention an important thing in martial arts?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/9314/5961). It's earnest and on-topic perhaps, but not a model question for the site as a whole.

Moderators can exclude questions from the hot network questions list. An excluded question appears as normal on the martial arts site but will not appear on the hot network questions list.

Is this something we want to consider doing in some cases? Or should we let the clickbait be?

Answer (score 1):

We should definitely not support clickbait.

Sexism and magical thinking in martial arts is prevalent enough that the question is actually somewhat representative of this site. See the past "ki/chi" questions.

On balance, leave it as it is. I doubt that it will attract much attention in any case.